# Locking on lazily created object returned from a function call

Tags: c#, locking

Can explain if and why the following code may not work as expected when calling Increment from multiple threads? Based on a test it seems to work, but it still looks fishy to me.

```
class Test
{
    public int Value;      

    private object _obj;

    private object Obj()
    {
        if(_obj == null)
        {
            _obj = new object();
        }
        return _obj
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        lock(Obj())
        {
             Value = Value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I would suggest that you try it out and then come tell us if something abnormal happens.

Comment: well this will lock only on one object because its singleton pattern. of course if value if `_obj` is not modified anywhere else

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? ^^

Comment: This won't work, because `Obj` method isn't thread-safe. There will be a race, when several threads will try to create lock object, because of incorrect singleton implementation.

Comment: It was code that previously locked on _obj (which was instantiated in the ctor), but then later changed to being lazily created.

Comment: Changing it to being created in the constructor solves the race condition issues. In reality the constructor is one of the few places you can be relatively sure that only one thread can be messing around :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race condition the first time `Obj()` is called, but *only* the first time.

Imagine that the method is run in parallell, then two different objects might be allocated and returned, but only if the second call is before the first one finishes and passes the `_obj == null` check before the first one assigns `_obj`.

This would have the effect that the two calls to `Obj()` would return different instances.

Example run: (n-thread) line-of-code

```
(1) if (_obj == null)
(2) if (_obj == null)
(2)   _obj = new Object();
(2) return _obj;
(1)   _obj = new Object();
(1) return _obj;
```

Comment: Ah ok, so then we could get locks on 2 different instances of `_obj` and there could be a race condition updating `Value`.

Comment: @mclaassen Exactly. In effect probably meaning that two very close calls to `Increment()` on two separate threads being that `Value` is only increased once.